# What's the best way to hightlight a telephone number in Android App?

Tags: android, style, style-guide

I was wondering what is a good way to make clear that you can click on a telephone number and immediately call someone without copying & pasting the phone number. How can I persuade a user to click on a phone number ?

I know I can underline the TextView as an HMTL link, but I want to try something different.

ps: my question is not about how to call someone when clicking on a phone number, but about how to style the phone number to show that it is clickable.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Nick!  Can you clarify your context? Why does styling the phone like a normal link not work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is, as you said, to underline it where clicking on it will activate the phone app.

Alternate solutions are all graphical-based, using the same mechanism but adding something to the number. Skype has a box around numbers, Google Hangouts puts a circle with an icon, etc. You can spend time doing that, but I recommend first offering the basic highlight function and changing it from there with A/B testing to see what the difference is. That way you have something to gauge against.

Answer (score 0):

So here are two very simple solutions:

**Underlined Phone Number**
Like @Jamezrp said you could underline the telephone number which would indicate that there is an action behind tapping the telephone number.

**Phone Number Button**
Alternatively, you could put the telephone number in a button with the text **"Call 00112345"** which would be very clear that clicking on the button will call the number.

As with most things, there is no one solution that fits all so I would recommend that you A/B Test the two options above to see which works the best for you!